# Multidriven nets: Synthesis ok, Simulation fails

Tags: simulation, fpga, system-verilog, bus

I have a fundamental understanding problem with System Verilog. I am working on a processor design, where some bus systems should be shared between several processing units (System Verilog modules). With an arbiter only one module at a time should be active, driving the bus, while all other are high impedance.

I got rid of the multidriven nets warnings in Vivado during synthesis and there are not anymore any bus conflicts, but the simulator gives a warning, that the bus signals 'might' be multidriven. I made a tiny example code and I would expect to get for 'data' '11', when 'select' is '10'?

While simulation stops at all in Vivado, it works with Cadence simulator, but with wrong results - [screenshot simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQeV9.jpg)

testbench.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module testbench_top();

logic [1:0] select;
logic [1:0] data;

top top_inst(.*);

initial
begin
  select = 0;
  #2 select = 1;
  #2 select = 2;
  #2 select = 0;;
end
  initial
    begin
      $monitor("t=%3d s=%b,d=%b\n",$time,select,data);
    end
endmodule
```

design.sv

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module top
(
 input logic [1:0] select,
 output logic [1:0] data 
);

driver_1 driver_1_inst(.*);
driver_2 driver_2_inst(.*);

endmodule



module driver_1
(
 input logic [1:0] select,
 output logic [1:0] data 
);
always_comb
begin
  if (select == 2'b10)
        data = 2'b11;
    else
        data = 'z;
end
endmodule



module driver_2
(
 input logic [1:0] select,
 output logic [1:0] data 
);
always_comb
begin
  if (select == 2'b01)
        data = 2'b01;
    else
        data = 'z;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you expect the value of `data` signal the `top` module, which is driven by the two outputs of your driver modules, to be resolved (e.g. when one drive `'z`, the other gets the bus.

This will happen if you declare the `top.data` signal as `output wire logic [1:0] data`.

Section **23.2.2.3 Rules for determining port kind, data type, and direction** of the IEEE 1800-2012 standard states that

> For output ports, the default port kind depends on how the data type
>   is specified: — If the data type is omitted or declared with the
>   implicit_data_type syntax, the port kind shall default to a net of
>   default net type. — If the data type is declared with the explicit
>   data_type syntax, the port kind shall default to variable.

In your case, the second clause applies, since you declared `data` as `output logic[1:0]`, meaning that it was interpreted as a variable and not a net. Multiple values on variables aren't resolved (and in some tools are also illegal).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!
Would there be a solution, when data is assigned via a non-blocking assignment (each driver has its separate always_ff block and the non-active sets its value to 'z again), because then a wire can't be used or?

Comment: @ES_major I think wires can only be driven by `assign` statements, so it won't be possible.